# Conditional summarizing columns

Tags: t-sql, group-by, case

I have the following situation

```
ID   Value
1    50
1    60
2    70
2    80
1    0
2    50
```

I need to run a query that would return summed value, grouped by ID. The catch is if the value is 0, then the entire sum should be 0.

Query results would be

```
ID   Value
1    0
2    200
```

I tried

```
select ID, case 
when Value> 0 then sum(Value) * 1
when Value= 0 then sum(value) * 0
end
from table
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select ID,
       sum(value)*sign(min(abs(value))) as [sum(value)]
from YourTable
group by ID
```

With a case if you like:

```
select ID,
       case sign(min(abs(value)))
         when 0 then 0 
         else sum(value)
       end  as [sum(value)]
from YourTable
group by ID
```

Comment: You can use a aggregate function in a case statement or you can put a case statement in an aggregate function. You can not check against a **un**aggregated value and return a aggregated value.

Comment: @John - Updated answer with a version using CASE.

Comment: Your original solution without using CASE is a much better idea.